# How to load Amazon website through Datapower

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

iam trying to load amazon website in datapower using dynamic routing using a xslt stylesheet,
the home page of the amazon wedsite is loaded with the datapower hostname but when iam trying to navigate to other category like Best Sellers iam getting an internal error.

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body>
<env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>URL Not Found (from client)</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'd like to point out that this use-case might not be the best to handle in XSLT and DataPower.
I'd recommend you to use GWS instead!

My guess is that the URL is "mangled" by DataPower as you might lose query-string parameters so make sure you log out the actual URL used.
Also note that DataPower does not handle redirects by default so if you are sent  any `30x` response DataPower won't like it.